# A simple problem involving $\Bbb Z_3[i] $ and units.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $\Bbb Z_3[i] = \{a + bi | a, b ∈ \Bbb Z_3, i^2 = −1\}$

a). How many elements are in $\Bbb Z_3[i]$? Explain.

I know that there are 9 elements but I also know that under multiplication this forms an abelian group with order 8 because $(a+bi) ^{-1} = \frac {a-bi}{a^2 + b^2}, a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$. I don't know which one is the correct answer.

b). Find the units in $\Bbb Z_3[i]$ and compute their inverses.

I determined that all the non-zero elements in this group are units according to what I have above because all the elements have inverses. But I don't know how to find them all. I'm assuming it wants me to find the multiplicative inverses.

So my though process for this is: $(1)(1) = 1$, $(2)(2) = 4$ mod $3 = 1$, $...$ How would I go about doing this for the elements containing $i$?

Comment: I also found inverses for $i$ and $2i$. There are four elements that I don't know how to find inverses for. Namely $1+i, 2+i, 1+2i, 2+2i$.

Comment: For the first part, what you have seen is that the *non-zero* elements form a group of order $8$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft so then, there should just be 9 elements?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Well, recalling that $2^{-1} = 5^{-1}=2$, you have $$(1+i)^{-1} = (1^2+1^2)^{-1}(1-i)=2-2i=2+i$$ indeed $$(1+i)(2+i)=2+2i+i-1=1+3i=1$$ You can proceed similarly to find inverses of other elements.

Comment: @Crostul I'm a little confused on how you got from $2-2i$ to $2+2i$. I did follow the rest of that though.

Comment: It's $2-2i=2+i$: this is because $-2=1 \Rightarrow -2i=i \Rightarrow 2-2i=2+i$

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. @Crostul Quick question though. Can I say that $(2+i)^{-1}$ is $(1+i)$ then?

Comment: @Nid Yes, of course you can say it without computing the inverse again (that's because $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$).

Comment: @Crostul ok, thank you very much. I'm trying to be concise in my work.